# How to not disclose Entityframework property names in GET request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have typical POCO classes representing models for a search functionality. The search is based on a GET request. Now when my form makes a GET request to the server, the Url discloses the class and property names as it is.

Users see for example the following Url, which seems a bit too long and intrusive too:

```
/search?Class1.Property=false&Class2.Something.Property=some_value
```

Is there a way to rename `Class1.Property` and so on without actually renaming my entities? Some kind of a mapper may be?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding naming conventions. `Class1.Property=false` would mean that the action method would be `public ActionResult (MyClass model)` where typeof `MyClass` contains a complex property named `Class1` which contains a boolean property named `Property`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using a ViewModel, which maps to an entity:

```
public class SearchEntity
{
    public bool SomeBoolProperty { get; set; }
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
}

public class SearchViewModel
{
    public bool opt1 { get; set; }
    public string q { get; set; }

    public SearchEntity ToEntity() 
    {
        return new SearchEntity 
        {
            SomeBoolProperty = opt1,
            SearchTerm = q,
        };
    }
}
```

Giving you the URL:

```
search?opt1=false&q=some_value
```

You can then use the `SearchViewModel` in your controller, while with `ToEntity()` you can generate an instance for saving to Entity Framework.

You can automate the mapping, for example using AutoMapper.